Movie about a dying boy who creates a fantasy world
I remember watching a movie a few years back about this young boy who was dying. His family consisted of himself, a little sister and a mum and dad.
I also remember that the boy wrote stories. I think he also narrated them during the film. 
Also, I vaguely recall a scene where the family pulls over on the road (possibly by a bridge) and the boy walks to his parents and asks them if he is dying.
The boy's illness causes him pains in the head.

Possibly the Disney movie The Four Diamonds with Christine Lahti from 1995:

Young Christopher Millard fantasizes about being a squire of the Round Table and studies the stars. But when his difficulty breathing turns out to be caused by a tumor, his fantasies turn into a means to battle the disease. Chemotherapy eats his summer and instead of writing the standard "What I did during my summer vacation", his teacher lets him write a fictional story, and Chris makes characters from the people around him. As Chris battles with doctor, treatments, and the illness, Squire Millard goes on a quest against an evil sorceress to gain the four diamonds of Courage, Wisdom, Honesty, and Strength: qualities that Chris himself attains as his health fails. 

He also has a little sister, and incorporates his parents into his fantasy. It was based on a real-life story. Here's the trailer, where he asks his parents why he's not getting better as they drive in a car on 0:15:



